# Laravel. Is there a way to pass an API Resource as a parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm familiar with the usage of the [Laravel Api Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources), I have used it for a single element like:

```
return new JsonResource($theResource)
```

and for a collection of elements with:

```
return JsonResource::Collection($theResources)
```

But now I want to pass a jsonResource to another class or method and be able to do the same, for example to do something like:

```
$theJsonResource->collection($theResources)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can pass classes to methods or classes as a string reference, which will help you in your case. New keyword is fairly straight forward and with the static call you have to use some PHP tricks.

```
class ResponseBuilder
{
    private $resource;

    public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function buildRessource($resource)
    {
        return new $this->resource($resource);
    }

    public function buildRessources($resources)
    {
        return call_user_func($this->resource .'::Collection', $resources);
    }
}
```